# Is it possible to use physical pixels instead of logical pixels for one particular image?

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive website and device pixel ratio (DPR) is not 1.

I want to show a photo and I want 1 pixel in the photo to be 1 pixel on the screen (only for photos).

I tried it out and it simply looks better if photos are not zoomed.

My code is simply

```
<img src="photo.jpg" />
```